# My visual c# 2010 express without start external program

Tags: c#, external

I want to use NUnit to run my class library.
So, I click the project's properties and I only see the"Start Option".
And where is my "start external program"?
I use Microsoft Visual c# 2010 express.

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is not available for express editions.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68c8335t.aspx

Comment: how about this one: http://stevedunns.blogspot.com/2007/03/running-unit-tests-in-visual-studio.html

Comment: and one more http://www.dijksterhuis.org/setting-up-nunit-for-c-unit-testing-with-visual-studio-c-express-2008/

Comment: You can run nunit when you press F5 because that is the debug.run activation. >> http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/9/6/296AAFA4-669A-46FE-9509-93753F7B0F46/VS-KB-Brochure-CSharp-A4-HiRez.pdf

Comment: Ok, how about post build event?

Comment: Maybe this will help somw way: http://tech.rofas.net/post/running-and-debugging-tests-with-visual-studio-express-edition.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is possible even in express editions.

1. Close the project.
2. Open the project's .csproj.user file in a text editor.
3. Modify to reflect the starting program as shown below.

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
    <StartProgram>D:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2014\acad.exe</StartProgram>
</PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```